# how to get last 14 days of android sms

Tags: java, android, sms

I am trying to read the last 14 days of android sms messages however it seems to take an eternity to read out all the messages from the Cursor so i limit it to the 1st 100 which dont seem to be in chronological order.

Any ideas of an efficient query of th esms  data in order to pull the contact and the message only?

My code:

```
Uri uriSMSURISent = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"); // get the sms data for sent
Cursor curSent = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURISent, null, null, null,null);

    int i=0;
   while (curSent.moveToNext() && i<100) 
    {
            String from = curSent.getString(2);
            if(sentHashmap.containsKey(to))
            {
                String cumulativeMessage = sentHashmap.get(to); 
                sentHashmap.put(from, cumulativeMessage+ " " +curSent.getString(12));
            }
            else
                sentHashmap.put(from, curSent.getString(12));
i++
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you use the ContentResolver query to get only the records that interest you.
you can select different columns, specify where clauses and even sort..

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html

```
// Queries the user dictionary and returns results 
mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
     UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,   // The content URI of the words table
     mProjection,                        // The columns to return for each row
     mSelectionClause                    // Selection criteria
     mSelectionArgs,                     // Selection criteria
     mSortOrder); // The sort order for the returned rows Table 2  shows how the arguments to


 query(Uri,projection,selection,selectionArgs,sortOrder) match an SQL
 SELECT statement:


// column names for above provider:
0: _id
1: thread_id
2: address
3: person
4: date
5: protocol
6: read   
7: status
8: type
9: reply_path_present
10: subject
11: body
12: service_center
13: locked
```

Now you just need to query it with a good where clause:

```
  long date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 14L * 24 * 3600 * 1000).getTime();
  Cursor curSent = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURISent, null,"date" + ">?",new String[]{""+date},"date DESC");
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it with the date code below but got nothing back, have i formatter it incorrectly?
Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 14L * 24 * 3600 * 1000);

result: Mon May 13 22:42:31 GMT+01:00 2013

Comment: got it - i needed to get the date in millisecs. thanks a mill man.