# How to break out of ContentResolver query?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have the following to read the SMS'es on the phone:

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
Cursor c = cr.query(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI, null null null);
if (c != null)
  if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
         ...
         if (enoughRead)
            break;
       } while (c.moveToNext());
```

The SMS'es are by default ordered by date descending. If I am interested in only recent messages, is that `break` statement sufficient to abort the query and save performance/memory? Is there any clean up I have to do?

The last parameter to the `query` method is `cancellationSignal`. Is it something I need to use for such a scenario?

Comment: You can pass a where clause in the query-method so you can filter all sms by date range. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780480/how-to-get-last-14-days-of-android-sms